# Writing controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller

I want using `ng-controller` to bring some data with using Bootstrap media object but i can't load data.
my code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
     content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
 </head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
          <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left media-middle">
                <a href="#">
                  <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{dish.lable}}</span>
                <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
            <p>Put the comments here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

    app.controller('DishDetailController', function() {

        var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image:'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category:'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                      comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

             this.dish = dish;

    });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

please help me...

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access a variable from the template, this variable must be on the $scope. If you only expose it on the controller itself (i.e. using `this.dish = ...`), then the controller itself must be on the $scope, using

```
<div ng-controller="DishDetailController as ctrl">
  ...
  {{ ctrl.dish.name }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
this.dish = dish;
```

for:

```
$scope.dish = dish;
```

Also, just after your module definition add:

```
$scope.dish = {};
```

Comment: Just add to it. Should add $scope in controller declaration as well. app.controller('DishDetailController', function($scope)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add **`controller as`** syntax in the `ng-controller` directive.

**Working Demo :**

```js
angular.module('confusionApp', [])

.controller('DishDetailController', function () {
   var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image:'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category:'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                      comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

             this.dish = dish;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="confusionApp" ng-controller="DishDetailController as myCtrl">
      <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left media-middle">
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="media-heading">{{myCtrl.dish.name}}
                <span class="label label-danger label-xs">{{myCtrl.dish.lable}}</span>
                <span class="badge">{{myCtrl.dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                <p>{{myCtrl.dish.description}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
            <p>Put the comments here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```